# failed with error code 1 when installing django-auth-ldap

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use django-auth-ldap so first of course I need to install it. I tried to just do pip install django-auth-ldap and that gives me the following problem:

```
C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install django-auth-ldap
Collecting django-auth-ldap
  Using cached django_auth_ldap-1.2.8-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyldap (from django-auth-ldap)
  Using cached pyldap-2.4.25.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from django-auth-ldap)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages (from pyldap->django-auth-ldap)
Installing collected packages: pyldap, django-auth-ldap
  Running setup.py install for pyldap ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hansong.li\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bak9l5f6\\pyldap\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z6tq2vvb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    defines: HAVE_SASL HAVE_TLS HAVE_LIBLDAP_R
    extra_compile_args:
    extra_objects:
    include_dirs: /usr/include /usr/include/sasl /usr/local/include /usr/local/include/sasl
    library_dirs: /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib64
    libs: ldap_r
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying Lib\ldapurl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying Lib\ldif.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    copying Lib\dsml.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\async.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\deref.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\libldap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\openldap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\ppolicy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\psearch.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\pwdpolicy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\readentry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\sessiontrack.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\controls\simple.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\controls
    copying Lib\ldap\cidict.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\dn.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\extop\dds.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\extop
    copying Lib\ldap\filter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\functions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\ldapobject.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\logger.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\modlist.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\resiter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    copying Lib\ldap\sasl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    creating build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\models.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\subentry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\schema\tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap\schema
    copying Lib\ldap\syncrepl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\ldap
    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    running egg_info
    writing dependency_links to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing Lib\pyldap.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to Lib\pyldap.egg-info\top_level.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    file Lib\ldap.py (for module ldap) not found
    file Lib\ldap\controls.py (for module ldap.controls) not found
    file Lib\ldap\extop.py (for module ldap.extop) not found
    file Lib\ldap\schema.py (for module ldap.schema) not found
    reading manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile'
    warning: no files found matching 'LICENCE'
    warning: no files found matching 'Modules\LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'Lib\pyldap.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building '_ldap' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Modules
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=2.4.25.1 -IModules -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/sasl -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/sasl -Ic:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include -Ic:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.5\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
    LDAPObject.c
    c:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bak9l5f6\pyldap\modules\errors.h(8): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\hansong.li\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\hansong.li\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-bak9l5f6\\pyldap\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-z6tq2vvb-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-bak9l5f6\pyldap\
```

So then I tried to download a windows binary of it, and tried:

```
C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts>pip install C:\Users\hansong.li\Downloads\python-ldap-2.4.27
Processing c:\users\hansong.li\downloads\python-ldap-2.4.27
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4d49q60t-build\setup.py", line 53
        print name + ': ' + cfg.get('_ldap', name)
                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\hansong.li\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-4d49q60t-build\
```

I also tried to download the wheel and install from there, it also failed and looks just like the first error. Now I am really confused at how to do about this.

Comment: You're using Python 3.5, but the version of ldap you're installing was written in 2.7, hence the syntax error. In 3.5, `print` is _a function_ and should be called like this: `print(...)`.

Comment: @ForceBru Thanks. Could I solve this by just replacing print with print() in the source code? Or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: I afraid you can't. This file may have hundreds of `print`s, so you could try using the __2to3__ tool to convert Python 2.7 to 3.x automatically. Also, you could take a look at [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). BTW, are you sure that there's no version of ldap for Python 3.5?

Comment: @ForceBru Well I think if I do pip install then the latest version is gonna be used right? and that is 1.2.8, which says "This version is supported on Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4". But yeah thanks

Comment: You need to install OpenLdap to fix the error from the installation using pip. The file 'lber.h' is part of this.